# Adding a background image to a list view Xamarin.Forms

Tags: image, listview, xamarin.forms

I have been struggling with this for a while. I have a simple list view that uses a data model to pull data. All I want is to put an image the size of the screen in the background

```
<ContentPage Padding="0,-20,0,0" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="xxxxxxxx.Pages.PrayersByCategory">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ListView RowHeight="55"  x:Name="lv_prayers_categories_page" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="false" SelectedItem="Handle_ItemSelected" BackgroundColor="Transparent" SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                        <Grid x:Name="cellGrid" Padding="15">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinition></Grid.ColumnDefinition>
                        <Label x:Name="lblPrayerCategory" Text = "{Binding prayerCategory}" FontSize="16" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                        <Label x:Name="lblPrayerCount" Text = "{Binding prayerCategoryID}" FontSize="16" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/></Grid></ViewCell>        
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: use the ContentPage's BackgroundImage property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list view fills the page, you can set the **ContentPage** background color :

```
    <ContentPage Padding="0,-20,0,0" 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="xxxxxxxx.Pages.PrayersByCategory"
    BackgroundImage="star_outline.png">
```

Comment: I have my image under Resources in the iOS project and the list view has a transparent background color but I don't see my image. Is there a different location you have to put the images in if you are referring to it as a BackgroundImage.

Comment: @logixologist can you take a screenshot of the image directory , maybe your images are not added correctly